How to set InclusiveNamespaces for signed references in node-soap?
I'm getting "An error occurred when verifying security for the message." from the SOAP service I'm working with. I suspect this is because the signed references do not account for inclusive namespaces.
The node-soap library lets you configure signed references like so:
const options: IWSSecurityCertOptions = {
  additionalReferences: [
    // References go here...
    'wsa:To',
  ],
};
const wsSecurity = new WSSecurityCert(privateKey, publicKey, password, options);
soapClient.setSecurity(wsSecurity);

This produces a signed reference like:
<ds:Reference URI="#_1">
    <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>
        EG__REDACTED__hI=
    </ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>

But, I need the signed reference to be like:
<ds:Reference URI="#_1">
    <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soap foo bar" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        </ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>
        x2Q__REDACTED__EI=
    </ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>


Notice the InclusiveNamespaces element. This of course would change the digest.
How does one do this?
I read through the node-soap docs and source code and didn't find anything.

node-soap uses xml-crypto which has a inclusiveNamespacesPrefixList option. node-soap doesn't expose these options when the SignedXml class is instantiated, https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/master/src/security/WSSecurityCert.ts#L74, and it doesn't offer the options when adding signed references, see https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/master/src/security/WSSecurityCert.ts#L181.
You have to write your own WSSecurityCert class and change these lines:
Part 1: Add the inclusive namespaces to the constructor
this.signer = new SignedXml(options?.signerOptions?.idMode, {
  inclusiveNamespacesPrefixList: 'foo bar',
});

Part 2: Change how additionalReferences are added
for (const name of this.additionalReferences) {
  const xpath = `//*[name(.)='${name}']`;
  if (!(this.signer.references.filter((ref) => ref.xpath === xpath).length > 0)) {
    this.signer.addReference(
      xpath, // xpath
      references, // transforms
      undefined, // digestAlgorithm
      undefined, // uri
      undefined, // digestValue
      'foo bar', // inclusiveNamespacesPrefixList
    );
  }
}

This will produce the desired result.
